# Delete unused video clips in Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

After finishing editing a video with Sony's *Movie Studio Platinum 12.0*, I'm left with a giant folder of uncompressed rushes. I would like to delete some of them to save disk space.

Is there an easy way to keep only the video files that I have used in a project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Vegas Pro, but I think this applies to the Movie Studio version as well. As far as I know there is no magic clean up button that removes the unused files from your folder. However, if you go to the 'project media' tab in Vegas, you will see reference icons of all the files that were used during your editing session including jpegs, and .wav files. This is an accumulation, so if you pulled a clip in and then decided to delete it from the timeline it will still show up here until you click the button with the lightning bolt icon, this updates this folder so it will show you everything that is currently on the timeline.

This can be your reference to manually remove from the folder outside of Vegas. Caution: if you delete a file that is in the timeline, Vegas will complain and ask you for the location of the file the next time you launch this session. Likewise, if you move or rename any clips that were in the timeline, Vegas will treat this like a lost file and you will have to show Vegas where it is.

Comment: FYI There is no lightning bolt in Movie Studio 13/14 but you can do the same via Tools>Clean Project Media.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to physically deleting non-used files:

1. Go to your video file folder and delete all the sfk files
2. Open your project in Vegas. Vegas will re-create all sfk files for files present in your project (assuming the audio is also present in the timeline). Wait some time until Vegas has finished doing so.
3. Press the lightning button in your project media tab and close the project.
4. Go to your video subfolder. It's pretty easy now to select all files without corresponding sfk file. Move those files somewhere else. (I guess it's not too hard to create a batch script for that job, but I haven't yet)
5. Open the project again and see whether Vegas complains about any missing files. If it does, bring back those files.
6. The remaining stuff doesn't seem to be needed.